# Need tips deciding on a memory model to upgrade

Tags: memory, motherboard

I'd like to change my RAM so I've been googling for some models... I have some questions:

> - What is the difference between for example 2x4GB and 1x8GB memory chips?
> - As I've read on ASRock's site, my motherboard H81M-HDS does not seem to support DD4 RAM: http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/H81M-HDS/?cat=Memory Can you confirm that? I'd really like to get a DDR4 memory, but if there's no way my motherboard's going to support it I will have to change it and then buy that, otherwise it would be just a waste of money.
> - And last but not least, if I were to hypothetically buy this RAM model: http://www.hyperxgaming.com/us/memory/savage would my motherboard support all of its features?

Thanks

Comment: The fact its an Intel H81 chipset means it can't support DDR4.  Your motherboard supports all DDR3 that run at the supported frequencies detailed in its [specification](http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/H81M-HDS/?cat=Specifications).  I don't know how to answer, your question with regard to, what the difference between 2 4GB modules and 1 8GB module is.  The difference seems obvious, 2 DDR3 modules or 1 DDR3  module, what specifically do you want to know?  Memory that happens to be faster then the supported frequencies will simply be downclocked to the fastest supported frequency.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that, there is no way to keep your CPU, and use DDR4.  The Intel H81 chipset does not support DDR4 memory.

Comment: Afaik, you can't even insert DDR4 RAM into a DDR3 slot. They have differerent connectors. so, if you want to switch RAM types, you need to switch MoBos. and if you do that, you usually also need to change the CPU, as a MoBo with support for DDR4 will have a different socket than one for DDR3.

Comment: Well, then I guess I'll stick to a DDR3 memory. Thanks guys!